# Undefined index fetching images from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to fetch images from my mysql database. For some reason I am getting "Undefined index: products" on the last line but I can't figure out why.

```
    $product_images = "SELECT ProductImage FROM products";
    $products = $connection->query($product_images);

    while($row = $products->fetch_assoc()) {
        $image = stripslashes($row["products"]); //undefined
 }
```

I have done this before and I'm basically reusing the code but so I have no idea why it doesn't work. Running the sql command in the db works fine.

Thanks

Comment: change **$row["products"]** to **$row["ProductImage"]**

Comment: I'm only getting a huge amount of hex code when doing so

Comment: `echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,  '.base64_encode($row["ProductImage"]).'">';`.  Need to change `png` to whatever it is. Might not want `stripslashes`, depends on how it was saved.

Comment: Thanks, that almost did the trick. Gotta figure out the rest myself

Answer (score 3):

`$row["products"]` should actually be `$row["ProductImage"]`, in order to align with the original field.

That error is caused because the field you are trying to read in the array is not in your select statement. You need to ensure that the array index you are trying to access from the result array is the same name as the field you are selecting in sql.

Comment: I am echoing a html document. When I replace the placeholder with the picture I only get hex code.   
  while($row = $products->fetch_assoc()) {
   $image = stripslashes($row["ProductImage"]);
   $shop = str_replace('prodimage', $image, $shop);
   
  }

echo $shop;

Answer (score 0):

This error usually means you're trying to access an array that doesn't exist,
Check if the index exists before you access it. Try using isset().